# Estados Duplicados

Tags: sql, magento

Como posso excluir todos estados duplicados do Magento?
Isso ocorreu devido a mudança do checkout utilizado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cara, eu tive exatamente o mesmo problema. Resolvi entrando no phpMyAdmin e deletando os itens duplicados das tabelas '`directory_country_region_name`' e '`directory_country_region`'. Infelizmente eu sou péssimo em SQL e não tenho conhecimento dos comandos, senão postaria uma forma mais eficiente de fazê-lo.

Comment: Foi a primeira coisa que fiz, mas infelizmente o erro persistiu.

Comment: Eu também deletei os itens duplicados das tabelas 'directory_country_region_name' e 'directory_country_region' e deu certo, lembre de atualizar o cache do magento.